# Select query in codeigniter not working with mysqli

Tags: codeigniter

Mysql query executed in mysql but not in mysqli and mysql is deprecated so what syntax I have to use for mysqli in codeigniter:

```
 $sql = "SELECT admin_email
                FROM `tbl_admin`
                WHERE `admin_email` = '" . $username . "' and `admin_password` = '" . $password . "'"; 
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Comment: Does the query actually get any results when using sample data direct from the database?

Comment: sorry for no updation but it works

Answer (score 2):

You can use Codeigniter Query Bulider

```
$this->db->select('admin_email');
$this->db->from('tbl_admin');
$this->db->where('admin_email', $username);
$this->db->where('admin_password', $password);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: check your table and column

Answer (score 2):

I hope it works...

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tbl_admin');
$this->db->where('admin_email', $username);
$this->db->where('admin_password', $password);

$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->row();

return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ...

```
 $this->db->select('admin_email');
 $this->db->where(
             array(
                'admin_email' => $username,
                'admin_password' => $password
             ));
 $query = $this->db->get('tbl_admin');
 $result = $query->row();
```

Hopefully it works in your end...

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->where('admin_email',$email);
$this->db->where('admin_password',$password);
$qry = $this->db->get('tbl_admin');
if($qry->num_rows() > 0){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: If possible please provide some detail/context to the code, you can use code comment as well.

Answer (score 0):

It will work fine only if you set your Query in the Model then load that model in your controller. Directly setting the query from Controller seems to have this issue.

Example:
From the Model: Example 'Users.php'

```
class Users extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function check_username($username) {
            $query = $this->db->query("select * from `user_login` where `username`='$username'")
            $query_result = $query->result_array;
            if (!empty($query_result)) {
                return $query_result;
            }
            return[];
        }
}
```

From the Controller: Example 'Userauth.php'

```
class Userauth extends CI_Controller {
public function process_forgot(){
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->model('Users'); //Model loaded here
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $check = $CI->Users->check_username($username);
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($check);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

Try it.